# Apigee Error - com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException

Tags: guava, apigee, apigee-baas

I need help to identify this error, over the last couple days my API hasn't been fully operational and one of the errors that occur is:

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException
```

This is the response from the PHP Apigee Library.
When Googling it, I found something related to the Guava library but I am clueless about what this is. Can anybody help to identify this?
Many thanks

Comment: I am having the same issues although I am using Python.

Comment: It could be updates their side